# How can I encrypt the userInfoConfig parameter while using the kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin provided by io.confluent?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, encryption, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

My spring boot maven application connects to the schema registry in order to download the schema files as below

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${confluent.version}</version>
        <configuration>
            <schemaRegistryUrls>
                <param>${schemaRegistryUrl}</param>
            </schemaRegistryUrls>
            <userInfoConfig>dummyid:dummyPassword</userInfoConfig>
            <subjects>
                <transactions-value>src/main/resources/avro/io/confluent/examples/clients/basicavro/Payment2a.avsc</transactions-value>
            </subjects>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
            <goal>test-compatibility</goal>
        </goals>
    </plugin>
```

I would like my `<userInfoConfig>dummyid:dummyPassword</userInfoConfig>` to be encrypted.

I understand that maven allows encrypting the passwords and storing them in settings.xml (ref: https://dev.to/scottshipp/how-to-encrypt-your-maven-password-408d)

However, unlike the `sql-maven-plugin` example below, the `kafka-schema-registry-maven-plugin` doesn't seem to allow `<settingsKey></settingsKey>` parameter to read the encrypted password from servers settings.xml

**settings.xml**

```
<settings>
...
  <servers>
  ...
    <server>
      <id>test.server</id>
      <username><!-- your database username --></username>
      <password><!-- the encrypted password --></password>
    </server>
  ...
  </servers>
...
</settings>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> <!-- 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT required -->
  <configuration>
    <settingsKey>test.server</settingsKey> <!-- id of server here -->
    <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip.com:1521:SID</url>
    <!-- username and password are not mentioned anymore -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any thoughts on how this can be approached?